# How to edit WooCommerce product link content?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In shop / category pages i have a list of all my products, I want to customize what is inside the `<a>` tag of the product link. So far I have achieved to this point but cannot advance:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'myprefix_woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );

function myprefix_woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open() {
    global $product;

    $link = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_product_link', get_the_permalink(), $product );

    /* Original link, add elements after */
    /*echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">';*/
}
```

This allow me to add HTML elements after or before the opening `<a>` tag, what I really need is to edit what is inside.

Comment: what you need to add - provide a sample link for how it look like? are you modfying link or adding new class?

Comment: @MujeebuRahman its local, I need to add new tags, however I now have the issue that `$product->get_stock_quantity()` always returns 0 even when positive.

Comment: Please update the code